# Why this simple code is printing wrong value

Tags: arduino

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);

Serial.println(4294967.0 * 200.0);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

output: 
858993408.00

when it should be 858993400.00

Answer (score -1):

On an Arduino float type variables are 32 bit floating point.  So they only have about 6 or maybe 7 digits of precision.  That's the thing about floating point numbers, the way that they are able to represent a larger range than the values that they hold is that they don't hold values exactly.

If you want to be able to work with exact values then you can't use floating point.  Convert to integers and use fixed point math instead.

Comment: Yes, fixed point math has limited precision too.  But the limit is bigger.  And you can choose the size of the integer you want.  If you use 64 bit integers you get an awful lot of digits of precision.  WAY more than you get with floating point on an Arduino.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I only use fixed point. It was just to say that you do not have infinite precision with that, which could have suggested by saying "working with exact value".

Comment: I guess you could have made that leap if you didn't read or consider the context of the question.  But I never said that anything had infinite precision.

Answer (score -1):

try with typecasting both variables with double and and pass it.

```
Serial.println((double)4294967.0 * (double)200.0);
```

i didn't compile it or tested it. I think this should work. 
Or else convert it to LONG type and use it.

Comment: unfortunately  it still output 858993408.00

Comment: `double` in Arduino (avr-based boards) is 32-bit, same as `float`.

Comment: double and float are the same on an 8bit Arduino.